# Sortable nested list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, nested-lists

I have a nested list. I'm able to move (drag/drop) itens between existing sublists. But I can't move an element and drop it to become the first subitem of one list.

[Let me show you](http://codepen.io/Ghaleon/pen/aOMWMV)
As you can see, I can:

- Drag /Drop the subitems on it's own sublist.
- Drag/ Drop subitems between Element 1 and Element 3 lists.

But what I need is to be able to drop any of these subitems to `Element 2`(as you can see, `Element 2`has no sublist yet). So it would become the first subitem of that list.

I know that If I add the `.Sortable` class to `Element 2` I'd be able to do so, but it would also allow me to drag / drop it, and I really don't want to do this.

Also I now I can create a function to `AddClass / RemoveClass` whenever it's empty and when it's not.  I'd like to know if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an empty `<ul class=sortable></ul>` to the second `<li>` so that when you drop subelements that `<ul>` can pick it up

Here like this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqLjqM)

Comment: Also remember to have some padding to that empty ul so that when you drop both you and jQuery should know where to :)

Comment: Thanks guys ! I'm pretty stupid e.e It's alright to do it, right ? Leave an empty UL there ?